# search a word in next lines after a first word has been found

Tags: unix, sed, grep

Let's take for example this file `textfile.txt` :

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
foo**word1**bar
foo
bar**word2**foo
foo
foo
bar
foo**word1**bar
foo
foo
bar**word2**foo
foo
foo
bar
foo**word1**bar
foo
bar**word2**foo
foo
bar
foo**word1**bar
foo
bar
foo
bar
bar**word2**foo
foo
```

What I am trying to do is : Search for a first word in a file, here the word is `**word1**`, and if this word has been found, search in the same line and the next two the second word, here it's `**word2**`

I tried to use `grep` to search the `**word1**`, with the `-n` option to get the line number. Then with this line number, extract with `sed` the matching line and the next two, and then do an other `grep` to search for the `**word2**`. It also should match each time `**word1**` and `**word2**`.

But it doesn't feel like it's the best way to achieve this.

In this example, there should be 3 positive matches : the last one doesn't work because `**word2**` is 4 lines ahead from `**word1**`, and I want a maximum of 2 lines ahead.

Concerning awk's output, I would like to output the line numbers where the two words matched, and also their respective lines where they have been found.

I also have a shell script returning output. What I would like to do is : for each matching couple words, print `"my_script_result" + "awk_result" > file`

Comment: `but it doesn't feel like it's the best way to do this` yup, awk would be better choice

Comment: and also what do you want to do with matched lines? just print them or further processing?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to precise : I would like to do further processing (print matched lines, lines numbers and other informations to a file). I tried awk and it looked way simpler at the beginning, but since I do it in a shell script, I didn't find a proper way to use the awk results later in my shell script

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43256075/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner may help:

```
awk '/word1/{ok=1}ok && /word2/{print NR,$0}' file
```

In above line, `/word1/` is your first word, `/word2/` is your second word. The output would be matched line numbers and the matched lines.

It works in this way:

The script reads lines from the beginning of file, once `word1` was found, set variable `ok =1 (true)`. The 2nd part check `ok AND word2 matched`, if satisfied, print the output. Thus, if `word2` was matched before we found `word1`, `ok` is `false`, the line will be skipped.

### edit according to OP's update:

```
awk /word1/{ok=1;s=NR}ok && NR<=s+2 && /word2/{print NR,$0}' file
7 bar**word2**foo
20 bar**word2**foo
```

Comment: Does it also work if there is multiple words matching in a same file ? for example 3 couples word1 / word2 in the same file. Also since I would like to add some informations coming from a shell script with the awk output, is there a way for example to get something like `"shell_script_output" + "awk_output" > file` each time the couple words has been found ?

Comment: Also, I specified that I would like to find the `**word2**` only in the couple next lines after the `**word1**`. Here in your script, I think it matches even if the `**word2**` is way later in the file.

Comment: @Whin3 can you make a better example, which contains all your requirement cases, also provide desired output. otherwise there would be more further ping pangs.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, I tried to explain it better.

Comment: @Whin3 what if three lines: `#1:word1, #2:word2 #3 word2` what do you want then?

Comment: @Whin3 also in your updated example, there should 2 (instead of 3) positive matches. check the update in answer

Answer (score 0):

Choosing grep from the tagged tools:

```
echo shelloutput && grep -nA2 "word1" EgrepToy.txt | egrep "word2"
```

Output:

```
shelloutput  
7-bar**word2**foo
20-bar**word2**foo
```

Since I am not sure whether I correclty understood "In this example, there should be 3 positive matches" (I think OP and I are somehow counting the "next lines" differently), I add an alternative to get three:

```
echo shelloutput && grep -nA3 "word1" EgrepToy.txt | egrep "word2"
```

Output:

```
shelloutput  
7-bar**word2**foo  
14-bar**word2**foo  
20-bar**word2**foo
```

Both solutions work basically identically:

- create desired shelloutput `echo shelloutput`
- continue immediatly to grep `&&`
- grep for the first word `egrep word1`
- including the right number of following lines in the output `-A2`
- adding the input file line number `-n`
- grep the result for the second word `| egrep word2`

Echoing shelloutput is a placeholder for anything you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing sed from the tagged tools:

```
echo shelloutput && sed -En "/word1/{/word2/{=;p;};N;/word2/{=;p;};N;s/^.*\n//;/word2/{=;p;};N;s/^.*\n//;/word2/{=;p;}}" EgrepToy.txt
```

Output:

```
shelloutput
7  
bar**word2**foo  
14  
bar**word2**foo  
20  
bar**word2**foo
```

Works like this:

- create some output `echo shelloutput`
- continue directly to sed `&&`
- Look for the first word `/word1/{`
- look for second word `/word2/{`
- conditionally print line number and found line `=;p;};`

  - fetch next line `N;`
  - delete first pattern space line, including newline, without terminating `s/^.*\n//;`
  - look for second word `/word2/{`
  - print line number `=;`
  - print matching line `p;`
- literally repeat that twice

If you want two matches, i.e. only two following lines scanned for word2, then only repeat once, simply by deleting one `N;s/^.*\n//;/word2/{=;p;};`.